# How to use Debugger.getStackTrace to retrieve runtime function call stack traces when debugging JS on V8 engine

Tags: embedded-v8

I've embed newest v8 engine into my c++ project to execute and debug JavaScript, when I was debugging JavaScript, to get runtime function call stack traces, according to the google's v8 debugging doc: "https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/v8/Debugger/" , I tried to send a Debugger.getStackTrace command to v8 engine, and there is an example of
what Debugger.getStackTrace command looks like :

`{ "id": 43, "method": "Debugger.getStackTrace", "params": { "stackTraceId": { "id": "6352323678", } }`

But the "id": "6352323678" in above JSON string is fabricated by me and not real. I don't know how to get the real value of properties "id" in stackTraceId obejct. Is there any c++ interfaces I can use to get current stackTraceId in v8 engine source,or is there any CDP v8 debugging command I can send to v8 engine to get current stackTraceId?

I am not able to find the answer from google v8 docs